# How to use a button inside v-text-field label slot

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I need to insert a clickable button inside v-text-field under label slot. Meaning that there will be label : " Start typing or Select Search Panel" where "Select Search Panel" will be a link or button.

I'm able to make it visible using the v-slot:label but the button is not clickable and onSearchPanelClicked in not triggered..

```
        <v-text-field class="input-field" clearable prepend-inner-icon="search" solo >
                        <template v-slot:label class="linkLabel" v-on:click="onSearchPanelClicked">
                            Start typing or <v-btn v-on:click="onSearchPanelClicked" class="link" flat > Select Search Panel</v-btn>
                        </template>
                      
       </v-text-field>
```

Is there any way to transfer click event to the element ? If I start typing the label must disappear like it used to work on v-text-field.

Regards
Jan

Comment: i dont think this is a way to go, you can just positione button on text field using css i dont really understand what you want, but i am sure there are better ways

Comment: Hi Mladen. Thank you for your answer. I'm afraid  this can be problematic when handling screen resize

Answer (score 0):

You have to overwrite your input `.v-label` CSS rule [pointer-events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events).

Vuetify sets the label inside a v-text-field like this:

```
.v-text-field .v-label {
  pointer-events: none; // unclickable element
}
```

So changing it to `auto` will enable your button inside v-text-field label to become the target of pointer events, just be aware of [deep selectors](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/scoped-css.html#deep-selectors) when working with `scoped` styles at your component.

```
.v-input.input-field .v-label {
  pointer-events: auto;
}

/* or for scoped styles */
::v-deep .v-input.input-field .v-label {
  pointer-events: auto;
}
```

In this example the rule is applied only to fields with your custom class `.input-field`, if you'd like to overwrite for all the v-text-fields just remove it from the CSS code.